# How to alias column in SQL plus

Tags: sql

When I write this query in sql plus show me error (ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias)

```
    create or replace view vw_salary as select dname ,
 (select count(*)  from employee where dno=department.dnumber) from department;
```

Comment: Before `From department` add `AS empcount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns in a view need to have a name.  So, you need `as` after the subquery:

```
create or replace view vw_salary as
    select dname,
           (select count(*) from employee e where e.dno = d.dnumber
           ) as NumEmployees
    from department d;
```

I strongly encourage you to use table aliases and qualified column names (that is *use* the table alias).  This is *particularly* important for correlated subqueries, where it is easy to make a mistake and that is hard to debug.

I also note that the view is called `vw_salary`, but there is no salary information.

Answer (score 1):

```
select department.dname, count(employee.dno) as empCount 
  from department 
  left join employee 
         on employee.dno = department.dnumber 
 group by department.dname
```

I think this will be more efficient than your current format

Comment: This query won't return departments that don't have any employees.

Comment: Still incorrect, it will return a count of 1 for departments with no employees.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to name the count expression ... try the following, you can change "TheCount" to any name you want to use.

```
    create or replace view vw_salary as select dname ,
 (select count(*) AS TheCount from employee where dno=department.dnumber) from department;
```